# Is the volume of the parabola $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$, rotated around the $y$-axis, bounded by the plane $y=2$, equal to $8\pi$?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I tried doing this through integration(Washer method) and got $8\pi$, but I'm unsure if it is correct. If wrong, how do you do this correctly?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. By editing the question text, please show us at least some of your work, e.g., the integral equation you used as a reasonable start, so we can better help you determine not only if your answer is correct but, if it's not, then what you did incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: Even if your answer is correct, without your work we cannot determine if you have  a correct solution, since some of your steps might also be wrong.

Comment: So seems as if I actually used disc method, and coincidentally got the right answer but my method missed a few steps which I think I've figured out. I didn't write my work cuz honestly I haven't figured out how to format anything yet, but I'll work on that. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Yes, the washer method isn't really necessary here.  The disk method can be viewed as the special case when the inner radius is zero.

Comment: Here's how to write [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cylindrical shells: $2\pi\int_0^{2\sqrt2}x(2-\dfrac {x^2}4)\operatorname dx=2\pi[x^2-\dfrac {x^4}{16}]_0^{2\sqrt2}=2\pi(8-\dfrac{64}{16})=2\pi(4)=8\pi$.

Disk method: 
$\pi\int_0^2(2\sqrt{y})^2\operatorname dy=\pi\int_0^2 4y\operatorname dy=4\pi[\dfrac {y^2}2]_0^2=4\pi(2)=8\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer seems to be correct. Express $x$ in terms of $y$ for the first quadrant ($x=2\sqrt{y}$) and do integration with respect to $y$:

$$
V=\pi\int_{0}^{2}\left(2\sqrt{y}\right)^2\,dy=8\pi\ \text{cubic units}.
$$